# My whirlpool Cabreo dryer isn’t drying put in heating element still not drying what can it be

Tags: dryer

My whirlpool cabreo dryer isn’t heating up changed the heating element but still no heat what can it be

Comment: Circuit test to see if you are getting 220v at the plug.

Comment: Check the manufacturer trouble shooting guide.  There is a relay that goes bad in dryers that feeds power to the element. Many diy ers  replace element when only relay was bad.

Answer (score 1):

The leading cause of a dryer not heating is a thermal safety on the power to the heating element.

These are usually attached to the heater or duct and usually easy to get to a plugged or limited air flow is the reason they usually open.

Comment: Good call Ed.  I hate it when people just throw parts at things (esp. hack auto mechanics) without doing basic diagnostics first, like "is the heating element getting power?"  Dryers are not exactly like the space shuttle, they are pretty simple.